# ruby: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0` not found (required by ...)

Tags: ruby, linux, emacs

I'm trying to edit a ruby file in my spacemacs editor.

When I open the ruby file I get this debugging information:

```
[rbenv] Using the currently activated ruby.
evil-line-move: End of buffer
Suspicious state from syntax checker ruby: Flycheck checker ruby returned 1, but its output contained no errors: ruby: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /home/sfernandez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/libruby.so.2.7)

Try installing a more recent version of ruby, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.  Thanks!
```

I've tried the solution from this post:
`https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375927`

I tried doing this after changing directory to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
sudo mv libcrypt.so.1 libcrypt.so.1.old
```

After I executed this line I was locked out from doing any commands with `sudo`. And received an error: `sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked`. I was able to get sudo access again by just refresh installing my system with Pop!_OS, I guess moving the link for libcrypt.so.1 caused something bad to happen, so won't do that again.

I'm sure this all makes sense, but I feel like I'm missing something and that this shouldn't be hard to fix. Would appreciate any guidance on this.

If it helps here's my system info with `neofetch`

```
             /////////////                sfernandez@pop-os 
         /////////////////////            ----------------- 
      ///////*767////////////////         OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64 
    //////7676767676*//////////////       Host: Inspiron 7559 1.3.1 
   /////76767//7676767//////////////      Kernel: 5.4.0-7634-generic 
  /////767676///*76767///////////////     Uptime: 9 mins 
 ///////767676///76767.///7676*///////    Packages: 1763 (dpkg), 20 (flatpak) 
/////////767676//76767///767676////////   Shell: bash 5.0.16 
//////////76767676767////76767/////////   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
///////////76767676//////7676//////////   DE: GNOME 
////////////,7676,///////767///////////   WM: Mutter 
/////////////*7676///////76////////////   WM Theme: Pop 
///////////////7676////////////////////   Theme: Pop [GTK2/3] 
 ///////////////7676///767////////////    Icons: Pop [GTK2/3] 
  //////////////////////'////////////     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   //////.7676767676767676767,//////      CPU: Intel i5-6300HQ (4) @ 3.200GHz 
    /////767676767676767676767/////       GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
      ///////////////////////////         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 
         /////////////////////            Memory: 2328MiB / 7828MiB 
             /////////////
```

After doing some more work on this I've learned a little about symbolic links. I know that libcrypt.so.1 is a symbolic link to libcrypt.so.1.1.0 after running `ls -l | grep "libcrypt.so.1"`  I get the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       39 Mar 10 12:24 libcrypt.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       17 Mar 10 12:24 libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   202760 Mar 10 12:24 libcrypt.so.1.1.0
```

Running `ls -l` after changing directory to `$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib` I get the following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sfernandez sfernandez       16 Jun 27 20:25 libruby.so -> libruby.so.2.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sfernandez sfernandez       16 Jun 27 20:25 libruby.so.2.7 -> libruby.so.2.7.0
```

Now, I think the problem is that `libruby.so.2.7` can reference the ruby code just fine, but it also needs access to whatever is referenced by `libcrypt.so.1`. Anyone got any ideas?

This question is still relevant please help

Comment: Having the very same issue. Those same commands work in terminal, but NOT in emacs terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue (pop_os 20.04 LTS, spacemacs 0.300.0@27.1).

The only way I managed to make it work was downgrading emacs to version 26.3.

[UPDATE]

So after about half a year I had to set up a new laptop and was faced with the same problem. After hours of debugging I've finally found my old answer and managed to fix the problem.

Again, the solution for pop_os is to install the app from the pop!_shop that is named **Emacs (Terminal)**.